# no entered date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Can I get a bit help how to combine `if(not(isblank)` and `if(isblank)` in formula below for SharePoint? I need to merge two formulas into one.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date_end);(Date_Implemnted));"";TODAY()-Date_start);
```

And

```
=if(ISBLANK(Date_start);"";TODAY()-Date_start)
```

i want something like this: If date_start is not inserted all fileds days_clsoed; days_open and days implemnted must be blank

[image: no entered date]

if only date_start is insterted it sholud calculate days_open as today()-date_start and leave days_closed and days implemneted blank
[image]

if date_start and date_end are entered it shuld only show days_closed and calculate them as today()-Date_end and leave the days_open and days_implemented blank
[image]

and when all dates are entered it should only show days_implemented as today()- date_implemented not days_closed and days_open
[image]

Comment: You are working with two different date columns here. Can you add required conditions and results with some explanation to your original question by editing it?

Comment: Do you want something like this: `=IF(ISBLANK([Date_Implemnted]);IF(ISBLANK([Date_start]);"";TODAY()-[Date_start]);TODAY()-[Date_Implemnted])`?

Comment: yes but it needs both conditions. if i replace one with not(is(blank)) it doesnt work correctly. I edited the question @GaneshSanap

Comment: i solved it myself. the topic can be locked